# Difference between Network and Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-domain, windows-server-2000

What is the real difference between **domain**(in Active directory) and **network**?

Is my question wrong?

or

what is difference between **domain in network** and **domain in Active directory**?

Answer (score 1):

A "network" in the sense I think you are asking for, is just a group of computers that can talk together using the Internet Protocol (IP), with or without a router that can connect it to other networks, like the Internet.

A Domain in this sense is a set of Microsoft software that helps a user use, manage and otherwise administrate a network full of windows computers. MS protocols help you login to remote services, share files and media, provides naming services, and apply policies onto client workstations. One of the main things you do with a domain, is set up an accounts database, so that every computer that is a member of the domain recognizes the all the accounts in the database, so a user can login to any machine they are authorized to use.

Active Directory is the Accounts database software. It controls a lot more, but most basically, it stores computer and user accounts, and creates a secure way for a user to login at a PC.

Active Directory is a huge subject (far bigger than I could describe here), but you can find a great deal online.

Comment: @amalamalpm Questions seeking product, service, or **learning material** recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @DavePostil, the question doesn't appear to fit any of the criteria you specify. Was there perhaps content to the Ops question/comments that I'm missing because it was deleted?